Integral inequality for radially decreasing function
I want to prove the following inequality rigorously:
Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $0<a<n$, and $0<r<\frac{|x|}{4}$. If $x_0\in B(x,r):=\left\{t\in\mathbb{R}^n:|t-x|<r\right\}$, then
$$\int_{B(x_0,r)}|y|^{-a}dy\leq\int_{B(z,r)}|y|^{-a}dy,$$ where $z:=\left(1-\dfrac{r}{|x|}\right)x$.
Intuitively, this should be true since the point $x_0$ is closer to the origin than $z$, thus the left hand side is not greater than the right hand side. But how to prove the above inequality rigorously? Any guidance would be appreciated.
Remark: this problem stems from the proof of Example $3.2$ in the book titled "Variable Lebesgue Spaces: Foundations and Harmonic Analysis".

Hint:  There are three volumes of interest: $B(x_0,r) \smallsetminus B(z,r)$, $B(x_0,r) \cap B(z,r)$, and $B(z,r) \smallsetminus B(x_0,r)$.  The volume $B(x_0,r) \cap B(z,r)$ is common to both integrals, so subtract it from both sides.
There is a circle, $\partial (B(x_0,r) \smallsetminus B(z,r)) \cap \partial (B(z,r) \smallsetminus B(x_0,r))$.  Draw the plane through that circle.  The two volumes are identified by reflection through that plane.  Note that each point $y \in B(z,r) \smallsetminus B(x_0,r)$ is closer to the origin that its reflection in $B(x_0,r) \smallsetminus B(z,r)$ (best seen by projection onto $\vec{x}$).  Then use the triangle inequality to show that the contribution from each point in the remaining part of the $z$-ball is at least as large as contribution to the other integral from its reflection.

How to use the triangle inequality？Can you give a detailed proof?

Let $\mathcal{V} = (v_1,...,v_n )$ be an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ where $v_1 = x_0/|x_0|$ and $(u_1,...,u_n)$ be a basis where $u_1 = z/|z|$. Then the change-of-basis matrix $\mathbf{B}_{\mathcal{V} \to \mathcal{U}} \equiv \mathbf{B}$ is an orthogonal matrix, and in particular $|\det \mathbf{B}| = 1$. So now start with the left had side and make the change-of-variables $t = \frac{|z|}{|x_0|}\mathbf{B} y \Leftrightarrow y = \frac{|x_0|}{|z|}\mathbf{B}^Tt$. Then $$\left| \det \frac{\partial (y_1, ..., y_n)}{\partial(t_1, ..., t_n)}\right| = \left|\det \frac{|x_0|}{|z|}\mathbf B \right| = \left(\frac{|x_0|}{|z|}\right)^n \geq 1,$$ where the last inequality is due to your observation that $|x_0| \geq |z|$. So, now we have
$$\int_{B(x_0, r)} |y|^{-a} dy = \int_{B(z, r^*)} \left| \frac{|x_0|}{|z|}\mathbf{B}^Tt\right|^{-a} \left(\frac{|x_0|}{|z|}\right)^n dt = \int_{B(z, r^*)} \left|\mathbf{B}^Tt\right|^{-a} \left(\frac{|x_0|}{|z|}\right)^{n-a} dt \\ = \int_{B(z, r^*)} \left|t\right|^{-a} \left(\frac{|x_0|}{|z|}\right)^{n-a} dt$$ where $r^* = r\cdot \frac{|z|}{|x_0|} \leq r$ and the last equality follows from $|\mathbf{B}^Tt| = |t|$ (since $\mathbf{B}$ is orthogonal). Now make a second change-of-variables $w = \frac{|x_0|}{|z|}(t-z) +z$ for which the Jacobian is:
$$\left| \det \dfrac{\partial(t_1, ..., t_n)}{\partial(w_1, ..., w_n)}\right| = \left(\frac{|z|}{|x_0|}\right)^n.$$
We now arrive at
$$\int_{B(x_0, r)} |y|^{-a} dy = \int_{B(z, r)} \left|w  + \left(\frac{|x_0|}{|z|}-1\right) z\right|^{-a} dw.$$ Since $|z| = |x| - |r| > \frac34 |x| > r$, the angle between $z, w$ is less than $\pi$ (you should draw a picture to convince yourself). So in particular, we have $\langle w, z \rangle \geq 0$ and so, writing $|s|^2 = \langle s,s \rangle$ and using linearity of the inner product and the fact that $\frac{|x_0|}{|z|}-1 >0$, we find $$\left|w  + \left(\frac{|x_0|}{|z|}-1\right) z\right|^2 \geq \left|w \right|^2 \implies \left|w  + \left(\frac{|x_0|}{|z|}-1\right) z\right|^{-a} \leq \left|w \right|^{-a}. $$Continuing the equalities above then gives $$\int_{B(x_0, r)} |y|^{-a} dy = \int_{B(z, r)} \left|w  + \left(\frac{|x_0|}{|z|}-1\right) z\right|^{-a} dw \leq \int_{B(z, r)} \left|w  \right|^{-a} dw.$$

why $\langle w, z \rangle \geq 0$？I can not understand this point.

Well, I see, this point can be deduced from $|w-z|<r$, $|z|=|x|-r$ and $|x|>4r$ and the inner product.
